# Probability that two random sets have at least one element in common

Tags: probability

We consider a finite field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number, i.e. $p$ is a 128-bit number.

Person $A$ chooses $d$ values drawn uniformly at random from the field. Also, person $B$ picks $d$ values drawn uniformly at random from the field.

**Question**: What is the probability that at least one of the sets elements are equal (or the sets have any intersection)

Answer (score 3):

We can assume that $2d\leq p$, for otherwise the two sets must have an element in common.

It's easier to find the complementary probability, i.e. the probability that the sets chosen by $A$ and $B$ have no elements in common:

Once $A$ has chosen $d$ elements, $B$ has $p-d$ choices for the first element, $p-d-1$ choices for the second, and so on. Therefore the probability that the two sets are disjoint is
$$ \frac{(p-d)(p-d-1)\cdots (p-2d+1)}{p(p-1)\cdots (p-d+1)}$$
hence the probability that there is at least one element in both sets is
$$ 1-\frac{(p-d)(p-d-1)\cdots (p-2d+1)}{p(p-1)\cdots (p-d+1)}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Am I right that in the case where $p=2^{128}$ and $d=2^{20}$ then the probability that there is at least one element in both sets is "Negligible"?

Comment: If you want to estimate the probability, it might help to write $\frac{(p-d)(p-d-1)\cdots (p-2d+1)}{p(p-1)\cdots (p-d+1)}=\frac{{p-d\choose d}}{{p\choose d}}$ and use Stirling's formula for the factorials.