# How to make the probability that two random sets have any intersection close to zero (negligible)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, finite-fields

This question is related to one of my question:

[Probability that two random sets have at least one element in common](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1841673/probability-that-two-random-sets-have-at-least-one-element-in-common/1841683#1841683)

---

Assume we have a field $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $p$ is a large prime number i.e. $p$ is a $2^{128}$ number)

I have two sets $S_1$ and $S_2$ whose elements are drawn uniformly at random from the field, and $|S_1|=|S_2|=d$.

---

**Question:** What should the sets cardinality, $d$, be to make the probability that  the sets have any element in common negligible?

Comment: I guess that would depend on what you consider negligible, no?

Comment: As shown by Shagnik, $\sqrt p$ is, indeed, the correct ball park figure. In other contexts this is often referred to as [the birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), at least I've heard of crypto people call it that in the context of [meet-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Am I right that we should have $d<\sqrt{p}$ to make the intersection probability negligible?

Comment: Shagnik's argument tells that collisions are negligibly rare, when $d=o(\sqrt p)$. So something like $p^{0.49}$ will do for large enough $p$. How large is large enough? Depends on what you mean by negligible! Shagnik's estimate says that the probability of a collision is roughly $d^2/p$. You can set this to be at a desired level, and solve for $d$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability that $S_2$ is disjoint from $S_1$ is $\frac{\binom{p-d}{d}}{\binom{p}{d}} = \prod_{j=0}^{d-1} \frac{p-d-j}{p-j}$.

This product is at least $\left( 1 - \frac{d}{p-d} \right)^d \ge 1 - \frac{d^2}{p-d}$.  If $d = o( \sqrt{p})$, this is $1 - o(1)$, and hence the sets are almost surely disjoint.

On the other hand, the product is at most $\left( 1 - \frac{d}{p} \right)^d \le e^{ - \frac{d^2}{p}} = o(1)$ when $d = \omega(\sqrt{p})$.  Hence the sets will almost surely intersect when the set size is large compared to $\sqrt{p}$.

For a heuristic argument, suppose $S_1$ and $S_2$ are formed by choosing each element independently with probability $q = \frac{d}{p}$.  The probability that an element is in both sets is $q^2$.  Hence the expected size of the intersection is $p q^2 = \frac{d^2}{p}$, which suggests that the threshold should be when $d = \sqrt{p}$.

Comment: Note that this problem is purely combinatorial, and does not use the finite field structure in any way.  (Also, having $p$ not be a probability here was very confusing!)

Comment: oh thanks, please feel free to edit the question. Also, in the last sentence it's said $d=\sqrt{p}$. Am I right that for the disjoint we should have $d<\sqrt{p}$

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified - there was nothing wrong with the question: $p$ is also standard for primes.

When $d$ is very small compared to $\sqrt{p}$, the sets are almost always disjoint.  When it is very big compared to $\sqrt{p}$, then the sets are almost never disjoint.  When $d$ is comparable to $\sqrt{p}$ (that is, $d = c \sqrt{p}$ for some constant $c$), the sets will be disjoint with some fixed probability strictly between $0$ and $1$ - so you will sometimes get disjoint sets, and sometimes the will intersect.  Hence to ensure the sets are disjoint, you need $d = o(\sqrt{p})$.